# calc() alternative for old mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, backwards-compatibility

I am using calc() for defining the background-size of a button, something like this:

```
button: {
  background-image: url('img/bg.svg');
  background-size: calc(100% - 48px);
}
```

Has anyone have ever came up with a solution that works on old mobile browsers?

Thanks.

Comment: Define *old mobile browsers*.

Comment: Old mobile browsers seem to be okay with calc - a few very old ones have issues with divide/multiply, but that's not what you're doing, so you should be fine. http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: No calc() and no flex-wrap: the cost of supporting Android <= 4.3 is too high for me (YMMV)